# iterating over a DataGridView in C# - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I have the following code:

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in DataGridObject.Rows)
        {
            MyDataSource.ForEach( 
                delegate( Product p)
                {
                    if (r.Cells["Product"].Value.ToString() == p.Title)
                    {
                        tally += p.Price;
                    }
                }
            );
        }
```

At the if statement on run time, I am getting the `error`:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' 
occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

What might be the problem ?

Any thought where i went wrong?

Comment: That `r.Cells["Product"]` is null and you are trying to access `Value` or `r.Cells["Product"].Value` is null and you are trying to call `ToString()` on it

Comment: Could also be that `p` is null, but less likely - have you tried debugging?

Comment: Well. r.Cells[ "Product" ] is not doing quite what I thought it should then.

How do I get the value from a column?

Comment: r.Cells["Product"].Value could be null

Comment: Do you have a column with "Product" exactly? Can you try index instead? 'r.Cells[1].Value' something like that?

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow r in DataGridObject.Rows)
        {
            MyDataSource.ForEach( 
                delegate( Product p)
                {
                    if(r.Cells["Product"]!=null)
                     {
                      if(r.Cells["Product"].Value!=null)
                      {
                        if (r.Cells["Product"].Value.ToString() == p.Title)
                        {
                          tally += p.Price;
                        }
                      }
                    }
                }
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

do it like this

```
             foreach (DataGridViewRow r in DataGridObject.Rows)
    {
        MyDataSource.ForEach( 
            delegate( Product p)
            {
                if (!string.isNullorWhiteSpace(Convert.ToString(r.Cells["Product"].Value)) && Convert.ToString(r.Cells["Product"].Value).Equals(p.Title,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    tally += p.Price;
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: @huMptyduMpty It will return null and if statement will fail. why won't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a column with "Product" exactly? Can you try index instead?

```
r.Cells[1].Value
```

something like that?

Also, you might have to convert it into a particular cell type? Ex: if its a textboxcell then you might have to do

```
r.Cells[1].Text
```

Answer (score 0):

need to check cell.Value for null

Comment: I was trying to edit the guys answer but he wont accept it, so im gnna make yours the answer.

Comment: @JamesT: Basically the `Moderators` has reviewed your edit and rejected. Not me !! But I suggest you to have `null` check on both `r.Cells["Product"]` and `r.Cells["Product"].Value`

Comment: Well why on earth are they doing that. I'm so sorry brah! I personally think your answer is far more comprehensive. Perhaps i'll now suffer the penalty but im going to mark yours as the correct answer.